# MPChart Android setCircleColor not reflecting

Tags: java, android, charts

I've been using MPChartAndroid Library.

I'm using

> setCircleColor()

to change circle color in lineDataSet
Strangely enough, methods `setCircleColor()` and `setCircleHoleColor()` are not working.

querying from the linechart by `mDataSet.getCircleHoleColor()` and `mDataSet.getCircleColor()` return new colors but the chart displays old color even after mChart.invalidate()

I've also tried

```
  mDataSet.resetCircleColors();
  mDataSet.setCircleColor(color);

  mDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
```

but seems like it's not working.

Although the methods

```
mDataSet.setColor()
mDataSet.setFillColor()
```

are working fine.

Is there a problem with Hardware Acceleration or am i missing something here?

Comment: I am using setCircleColor and getCircleHoleColor. They are working fine but I am defining it before adding the LineDataSet to the LineData, then I assign the LineData to the LineChart and I call invalidate metod on LineChart

Comment: What is the type of the color variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `LineChartRenderer` class stores bitmap cache for circle bitmaps for each dataset.

New Bitmaps are generated if this method in `LineChartRenderer`  returns true.

```
   /**
         * Sets up the cache, returns true if a change of cache was required.
         *
         * @param set
         * @return
         */
        protected boolean init(ILineDataSet set) {

            int size = set.getCircleColorCount();
            boolean changeRequired = false;

            if (circleBitmaps == null) {
                circleBitmaps = new Bitmap[size];
                changeRequired = true;
            } else if (circleBitmaps.length != size) {
                circleBitmaps = new Bitmap[size];
                changeRequired = true;
            }

            return changeRequired;
        }
```

**Hence even if new color is set via `setCircleColor()` or `setCircleHoleColor()` new bitmaps are not created so chart displays old color circles.**

This problem can be solved either by

1. Clearing Bitmap cache array. (Not possible without importing library as module as `circleBitmaps` is private)

2.Using a custom **LineChartRenderer**

3.By tricking the `init()` method to return true.
So to **dynamically** change circle color,use

```
 mDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
int colorCount= mDataSet.getCircleColors().size();
mDataSet.resetCircleColors();
mDataSet.setCircleColor(color);
if(colorCount==1){mDataSet.getCircleColors().add(color);}
```

instead of

```
 mDataSet.setCircleColor(color);
```

and to change circle hole color **dynamically** , use

```
mDataSet.setCircleColorHole(color);
int circleColor= mDataSet.getCircleColors().get(0);
int colorCount = mDataSet.getCircleColors().size();
mDataSet.resetCircleColors();
mDataSet.setCircleColor(circleColor);
if(colorCount==1){mDataSet.getCircleColors().add(circleColor);}
```

instead of

```
 mDataSet.setCircleColorHole(color);
```

> NOTE: This only works if you plan to use single circle color!
>           Tested on MpChartAndroid v3.0.2

Thanks @cristallo for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using setCircleColor and getCircleHoleColor. They are working fine but I am defining it before adding the LineDataSet to the LineData, then I assign the LineData to the LineChart and I call invalidate method on LineChart

lineChart is a com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart

```
LineData lineData = new LineData();
LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineDataEntries, null);
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
lineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false);
lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR);
lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet);
lineChart.setData(lineData);
lineChart.invalidate();
```

NOTE: MpChart setCircleColor doesn't accept R.color.id as parameter. You have to use a Color type or create a new one from the resource color id before using it. It can be done using ResourcesCompat.getColor method.

Comment: i'm using int colors so it's not a problem.

Comment: and i'm not willing to delete  dataset and add again instead i have dataset eference stored and i'm modifying it. Does removing dataset and adding again to Linedata object make a difference? Because setFillColor ,setFillAlpha and setColor are working well without replacing dataset with modified copy

Comment: I am not sure if the color of the circle can be changed after the dataset has added to the linedata. Can you verify how many elements are present in the circle color list. It can be done using LineDataSet.getCircleColors() method? ... just to be sure that it is as expected (only one element with the right color)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:
For using different circle colors:

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(true)
                val colorCount: Int = lineDataSet.circleColors.size
                if (colorCount>0){
                    lineDataSet.resetCircleColors()
                    lineDataSet.circleColors.addAll(multipleCircleColorList)
                    if (colorCount == multipleCircleColorList.size) {
                        lineDataSet.circleColors.add(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                    }
                }
lineChart.invalidate()
```

The answer is based on @Omkar's Answer. Thanks @Omkar